# Why can't Swift infer type here?

Tags: swift

I have this code with an `associatedtype` :

```
protocol ATState {
    associatedtype Event
    func nextState(event:Event) -> Self?

}

enum ATPlayerState:ATState {


    case weak, powerful, poweringUp, poweringDown

    func nextState(event: String) -> ATPlayerState? {
        return nil
    }

}
```

But there is a compile-time error : "ATPlayerState does not conform to protocol ATState" ; there is a fix-it to add `typealias Event = <Type>`, **if I add : `typealias Event = String`, it fixes the error**.  But I don't understand **why** I need to do this !

When I read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189) I see that :

> Thanks to Swift’s type inference, you don’t actually need to declare a
>   concrete ItemType of Int as part of the definition of IntStack.

*Also, the examples don't use type alias, they just implement the methods.*

So shouldn't the associated type be inferred here ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is a known bug, the `Self` return is the culpret – see [SR-2746](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2746). Simply adding a `typealias` to the conforming type to explicitly satisfy the associated type looks like the simplest workaround.

Comment: @Hamish Oh thank you ! I thought I had misunderstood something... hope it will get fixed soon !!

Answer (score 0):

When you add your Event as typealias, compiler does not give an error? This code block works just fine.

```
enum ATPlayerState:ATState {

    case weak, powerful, poweringUp, poweringDown

    typealias Event = String

    internal func nextState(event: String) -> ATPlayerState? {
        return .powerful
    }

}
```

Comment: As explained in my question, I do know that adding a type alias fixes the problem. My question is about why I need to do that, since in Apple examples (that you can see in the link of my question) it seems that it is inferred !

Comment: The Apple example uses the  `typealias ItemType = Int` as you see first of all. Secondly you should just proived your type while using the protocol. You are just giving the promise while using `associatedtype` keyword.

Comment: I had missed that in the example they are using it, but as they explain, it's not needed. It's actually a bug from the Swift compiler ! (as @Hamish explained under my question).